# Check for pdf contents to file to find the pdf is password protected

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, aspose

I am trying to find that the PDF is encrypted or not. I am facing issue while uploading my documents generated by our application. It works fine for the other PDF.

I figured out that this happens because my PDF file contents the Encrypt Metadata true, even my file is not password protected.

```
trailer
<</Size 49
/Root 46 0 R
/Encrypt 47 0 R
/ID [<544779292784d1082d90221fd2118106><544779292784d1082d90221fd2118106>]
/Info 48 0 R
>>
startxref
218840
%%EOF


<<
/Filter/Standard
/R 3 /V 2 /Length 128
/O<0a9c59beafa2ba093c4bace402aae8e14eacb78a9ab178187f5922be0f044f63>
/U<a1b38ac6f6fe4d59b099045b71b52d7328bf4e5e4e758a4164004e56fffa0108>
/P -1852/EncryptMetadata true
>>
```

Can someone help in finding how should i check that my PDF file is just Encrypt Metadata as true while it is not password protected.

Comment: You mention itext and aspose. How do they relate to the issue at hand?

Comment: Itext and aspose can be used to manipulate with the pdf contents

Comment: *"how should i check that my PDF file is just Encrypt Metadata as true while it is not password protected."* - There is a misconception in your request:  *your file **is** password protected*! Most likely the password is the default password (so you aren't asked to enter it) but it is password protected nonetheless.

Comment: how can we differentiate that the file is password protected but it does not require password to open the file, do we have any mechanism to identify?

Comment: Try to use an empty password `""` to open the pdf in your program. If that works, it does not require a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may differentiate between encrypted and password protected PDF files with Aspose.PDF for .NET API. `PdfFileInfo` class exposes some bool properties including `IsEncrypted` `HasEditPassword` and `HasOpenPassword` which can be checked to achieve your requirements. Below is a code snippet for your kind reference:

```
        // Load source PDF file
        PdfFileInfo info = new PdfFileInfo();
        info.BindPdf(dataDir + "Test.pdf");
        if (info.IsEncrypted)
        {
            // Determine if the source PDF is encrypted
            Console.WriteLine("File is encrypted");
        }
        if (info.HasEditPassword)
        {
            // Determine if the source PDF has edit password
            Console.WriteLine("File has edit password");
        }
        if (info.HasOpenPassword)
        {
            // Determine if the source PDF has open password
            Console.WriteLine("File has open password");
        }
```

We hope this will be helpful. Feel free to let us know if you need any further assistance.

**PS**: I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: This works for normal pdf,while in case of my pdf which is not password protected, IsEncryted returns true bcz EncryptMetadata true and in /filter /Standard algo is used.

Comment: i want to know how can we differentiate between file that is password protected and file which is just EncryptMetadata.

Comment: Would you please share a sample PDF file via Google Drive or Dropbox so that we may investigate further to help you out.

Comment: Your PDF file is an encrypted file with 128 bit RC4 algorithm encryption, and has an edit password as well. I have updated my answer and respective properties can be checked with updated code snippet.

Comment: Can we do the same using code and not using any third party library

Comment: *"Can we do the same using code and not using any third party library"* - The third party library is merely code, so yes, you can, you merely have to develop the equivalent of (a huge part of) that library in code.